# Intersection | Subspaces | Span

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are two subspaces of a vector space $V$, then $W_1+W_2$ is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $W_1$ and $W_2$, right? Is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $W_1$ and $W_2$ the span of $W_1 + W_2$? If so, how do I demonstrate this?

Is this diagram correct?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of "diagram" you could want here.

Comment: You know how Feynman saw things through diagrams and that was like a novel idea. Try that.

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to diagrammatically conceptualize this notion.

Comment: @Trancot: That diagram won't help you. Just use the definitions. Whatever Richard Feynman did is not relevant here.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I just want another way of seeing this rather than definition definition definition.

Comment: What is the difference between all subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ and all subspaces $W_1$ and or $W_2$? Which is meant here? Does "all the subspaces of $V$ containing $W_1$ and $W_2$" mean that each subspace must contain both or just one just as long as other contain the other?

Comment: I get the feeling that mathematics is a bit weak. Tracing things back to the definitions seems almost like believing a religion. I don't know. Things will be more clear in the future I suspect.

Comment: @Trancot That's almost like saying "I feel language is a bit weak. Everything traces back to the words and the definitions." You have to learn the notes before you can play the song.

Comment: I don't believe so. I play the piano. I played by sound. Organic music sounds better.

Comment: So you learned to play the piano entirely by ear? That's quite impressive.

Comment: @EuYu (Parov Stelar - Requiem For Annie) Maybe you will like to hear these sounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an interesting question but first a disclaimer. Pictures can be intuitive but that also means that they are very personal. It can be a bit dangerous at times to do mathematics through diagrams, especially when it comes to linear algebra which aims to represent high dimensional spaces. Arguably the reason linear algebra is useful is precisely because it allows us to represent mathematically what we can't represent diagrammatically (i.e $n$-dimensional space). If you find this discussion hard to follow, well I tried my best.

First consider two lines passing through the origin in $3$-dimensional space spanned by two linearly independent vectors. Let's say $W_1$ is the first line and $W_2$ is the second line. You may know that the union of two subspaces is not a subspace itself (unless one vector space is entirely contained within the other that is) and it's useful to ask yourself why that is. The reason is because the union misses out on a lot of space *in between* the two subspaces.

The subspace $W_1 + W_2$ essentially takes the union and *fills in* the missing space. With our two lines, we fill in the spaces between the two lines and we get a plane. This is the key visualization here, that $W_1 + W_2$ takes the two subspaces and fills in  the spaces between them. The interiors of subspaces are inherently closed.

[image]

Let us depict subspaces as closed rectangles. The interior of each rectangle is the set of all vectors belong to that corresponding subspace. Let's say we have $W_1$ in red and $W_2$ in blue. The two subspaces may or may not intersect (i.e. intersect trivially), it does not matter.

We construct $W_1+W_2$ by taking the union of the two rectangles and filling in the spaces to create another closed rectangle. This is the rectangle shaded in purple in the image.

Now, if any subspace hopes to contain *both* $W_1$ and $W_2$ then it must also contain $W_1 + W_2$. This is represented diagrammatically as well. Any rectangle which hopes to contain both the red and blue rectangles must also contain the purple rectangle. There can be a bunch of subspaces which contain $W_1 + W_2$, and these are indicated in green.

But what is clear is that the purple rectangle is the *smallest* one which can contain both the red and the blue (for one, it's contained in every other rectangle satisfying the property). This is pretty much by construction. This is why $W_1 + W_2$ is the intersection of all the subspaces which contain both $W_1$ and $W_2$, precisely because it is the smallest subspace to do so.

**Note:** In case it is not clear, it is very common to denote the smallest object satisfying some property to be the intersection of all objects satisfying that property. Indeed the two are equivalent.

Specifically in our case, let $\bigcap W$ denote the intersection of all subspaces which contain both $W_1$ and $W_2$. Let $W'$ represent a subspace of the smallest dimension which contains both $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Clearly $\bigcap W \subseteq W'$ since $W'$ is one of the subspaces in the intersection. Conversely, since $\bigcap W$ is a subspace of $W'$ it follows that $\dim \bigcap W \le \dim W'$. But $W'$ was defined to be a subspace of smallest dimension. It follows that $\dim \bigcap W = \dim W'$ whence $\bigcap W = W'$.

Comment: Don't the subspaces have to intersect because of their necessary zeros?

Comment: How is "the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $W_1$ and $W_2$" written in symbol-form?

Comment: @Trancot I essentially consider $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ to be the empty intersection here. When I say they "don't intersect", I really mean they have trivial intersection.

Comment: @Trancot You're free to call it whatever you want. Some mathematicians like to give it a one letter name like $U$ or $V$ just like any other vector space. Some mathematicians like to use $\bigcap$ to denote the intersection. It's a notational choice.

Comment: So The intersection of all subspaces containing both of these other subspaces is written something like this $U_1\cap U_2\cap\cdots \cap U_k$. If so, does this also mean $(U_1\cap U_2)\cap U_3 \cap \cdots \cap U_k$?

Comment: @Trancot It's an infinite intersection and intersection is associative.

Comment: Associative + Infinity = ?

Comment: I feel like if I'm going to actually learn anything I have to understand what this ritual belief in infinity is first.

Comment: @Trancot What are you talking about? There are very likely infinitely different subspaces which contains $W_1 + W_2$, of course the intersection is infinite. The fact that the intersection is associative is independent of the fact that the intersection is infinite.

Comment: How is associativity defined for infinitely many objects?

Comment: I guess I should've been more clear. In general it makes no sense to talk about associativity on infinite sets. The intersection is defined as a separate set which satisfies certain properties and it is uniquely defined. It does make sense to talk about associativity on finite intersections however in which case the operation _is_ associative. If you're interested in foundational properties of sets then I suggest you grab a book on set theory.

Comment: I have one. It's Shen's "Basic Set Theory." All I'm saying is that it seems reasonable that successively unioning of sets containing these two subsets will eventually hone in on $W_1+W_2$. See my recent edit.

Comment: @Trancot The intersection is just the smallest subspace. There is no sense of "honing in" since there is no _order_ defined in the intersection. The intersection is defined as a set containing all elements of a certain index set. Sets inherently have no order within them.

Comment: Perhaps this has an application in object-shape detection. What idea is behind detecting the shape of an object by radar? I mean what mathematics is used?

Comment: @Trancot Maybe, who knows. What makes you think so? Do you want to join a chat room? This is getting a bit long winded and I suspect you have some more questions.

Comment: Subspaces can be represented by matrices. Matrices can have these kinds of subspaces. Randomly produces matrices with certain algorithmic boundaries might be able to find the "shape" of some defined "$W_1+W_2$". I don't know. Just a wild thought.

Comment: Matrices never represent subspaces though. Matrices represent linear mappings acting between vector spaces. And it's difficult to talk about the "shape" of a subspace. A $1$-dimensional subspace is just an infinite line. A $2$-dimensional subspace is an infinite plane. $3$-dimensional subspace is infinite space. So on...

Comment: What are you talking about? A vector is a matrix. A vector can represent an $n-$tuple like $F^n$, and $F^n$ certainly has subspaces. I'm talking about finite-dimensional spaces. About your comment below: I don't know.

Comment: A _vector_ is any member of a vector space. A _Euclidean vector_ is indeed an $n$-tuple but it _does not_ represent $F^n$. $F^n$ is the _collection_ of all $n$-tuples (with appropriate structure imposed). In what way does a single Euclidean vector represent a subspace?

Answer (score 0):

Well, $W_1 + W_2$ certainly contains $W_1$ and $W_2$, so you only need to prove that if $U \supset (W_1 \cup W_2)$ is a v.s. then $U \supset (W_1 + W_2)$.

So suppose $U \supset (W_1 \cup W_2)$ is a vector space.  Pick $v \in (W_1 + W_2)$. Then we can write $v = w_1 + w_2$ for $w_1 \in W_1$ and $w_2 \in W_2$.  Thus, $v \in U$, since $w_1, w_2 \in U$.

Comment: $U$ is what now?

Comment: It's an arbitrary vector space containing $W_1$ and $W_2$.